# How to use StepMonitor in NMinimize when using vector variable

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization

**Bug persists through 12.0**

---

For example, when I call this code

```
res = NMinimize[{Abs[{Indexed[qi, {1}] + 2, Indexed[qi, {2}], 
      Indexed[qi, {3}]}].{1, 2, 1}, 
   Norm[{Indexed[qi, {1}], Indexed[qi, {2}], 
       Indexed[qi, {3}]} - {0.3, 0, 0.2}] < 10}, 
  qi \[Element] ImplicitRegion[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 < 100, {a, b, c}]]
```

I get some answer, but I can't print intermediate results with StepMonitor. When I run this code

```
res = NMinimize[{Abs[{Indexed[qi, {1}] + 2, Indexed[qi, {2}], 
      Indexed[qi, {3}]}].{1, 2, 1}, 
   Norm[{Indexed[qi, {1}], Indexed[qi, {2}], 
       Indexed[qi, {3}]} - {0.3, 0, 0.2}] < 10}, 
  qi \[Element] ImplicitRegion[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 < 100, {a, b, c}], 
  StepMonitor :> Print[Indexed[qi, {1}]]]
```

I get this error message

```
Block::dup: Duplicate local variable Indexed found in local variable specification {Indexed,Indexed,Indexed}.
```

Disclaimer, this is not the real problem I'm solving, but rather a simplified version which shows exact same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug. You can work around the issue by avoiding [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed) (I also needed to include an explicit [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method) option in M12):$\in$

```
res = NMinimize[
    {
    Abs[{q1+2,q2,q3}].{1,2,1},
    Norm[{q1,q2,q1}-{0.3,0,0.2}]<10
    },
    {q1,q2,q3} ∈ ImplicitRegion[a^2+b^2+c^2<100,{a,b,c}],
    Method->"NelderMead",
    StepMonitor:>Print[{q1,q2,q3}]
]
```

> {0.0556604,-0.287369,0.30879}
>
> {0.0556604,-0.287369,0.30879}
>
> {0.0199391,0.116113,-0.507085}
>
> ...
>
> {4.4409*10^-16, {q1 -> -2., q2 -> -1.8128*10^-22, 
>     q3 -> -2.07681*10^-22}}

Comment: Thanks, it works. It's a bit ugly since I have a vector with 7 components, but it works